# Winform DragDrop Event Efficiency

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, event-handling

My son and I are working on a hobby project together (Winform app) for the dice game of Farkle and need guidance on handling dragdrop events for the dice. Please note we are not looking for the answer, or the code; just some general ideas on solution attack.

**Here are the constructs:**

**RolledDice**
—We have a single form with two panels. One panel contains 6 PictureBoxes which display dice images from an ImageList based on a DiceRoller class we built to generate random integers from 1 to 6. We are using a backing PictureBox array to iterate over each of the PictureBoxes. The click event for a “Roll Dice” button displays the rolled dice—all is good, this works great.

**PlayerDice**
—The second panel is configured identically to the first one and accepts user selected dice dragged from the Rolled Dice panel. Our use case requires the ability for the user to drag dice from the Rolled Dice panel to the Player Dice panel, and back again if the user changes their mind about the dice they want to keep—all is good, this works great.

**Problem Statement**
—Although we can drag dice from the Rolled Dice panel to the Player Dice panel (and update the backing PictureBox arrays in the process), it seems necessary to have three event handlers for each of the 6 PictureBoxes in both panels (MouseDown, DragEnter and DragDrop), and this amounts to a ton of code.

**Question**
—Is there an elegant way to have one set of these 3 event handlers for ALL Rolled Dice and one set of these event handlers for ALL Player Dice, rather than having a bunch of stringy code like we have now?

Again, we are not looking for the exact answer or the code, just some general ideas on solution attack.

EDITED:
Here is the code we have for ONE image.

```
    #region Mouse and Drag Events
    // Mouse and Drag Events for ONE Rolled Dice
    void pbRolled1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox source = (PictureBox)sender;
        DoDragDrop(source.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
    void pbRolled1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    void pbRolled1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox destination = (PictureBox)sender;
        destination.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }

    // Mouse and Drag Events for ONE Player Dice
    void pbPlayer1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox source = (PictureBox)sender;
        DoDragDrop(source.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);
    }
    void pbPlayer1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap))
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }
    void pbPlayer1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox destination = (PictureBox)sender;
        destination.Image = (Bitmap)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: You definitely exaggerate "ton of code", these event handlers are suitable for all pictureboxes.  You however didn't write enough of it, drag an image from Explorer to see it go wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to have a 1-to-1 relationship between controls and their events - events may be shared between controls.

Since you don't want a specific answer, I'll give you a general example.  Take this simple form, with three buttons and a label:

[image: Simple Windows Form]

Now, the code for this simple form is as follows (Form1.cs):

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
            this.button3.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = (sender as Button);
            if (button != null)
            {
                label1.Text = string.Format("You pressed {0}", button.Text);
            }
        }
    }
```

You could add the events in Design mode, and select the same event for each.  I hooked up the events in the constructor just to make it a little more obvious example.

Notice that all three button click handlers point to a single event handler.  That handler will look at the `sender` of the event to see which button was pressed.  It then just takes the caption of the button, and displays it in a message in the label.

You can do the similar things with the duplicate events you are creating now (especially after looking at the code you added to your question).

Answer (score 0):

Well the mouse events are handled by the Windows form so that implementation will need to be done on the form but for the drag events you could have your picture boxes implement the IDropTarget interface so that code could be consolidated and give you some reuse and cleaner code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! We will research the IDropTarget interface and its implementation. Much appreciated.